# Azure DevOps pre-deployment approvals minimum quantity

Tags: azure-devops

In Azure DevOps release pre-deployment approvals have the following Approval order options:

1. "Any order" (all have to approve)
2. "In sequence" (all have to approve)
3. "Any one user" (one approve is enough)

I want to have pre-deployment approval policy that will allow deployment if 3 of 5 people confirmed release, how is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure DevOps release pre-deployment approvals doesn't support configuring minimum number of approvers to complete the approval. You could submit a suggestion at website below:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21

As a workaround, you can create a pipeline with multiple stages, then you can manually control when a stage should run using approval checks. In Approvals and Checks for the resource, you can configure minimum number of approvers to complete the approval.

[image]

Comment: "Approvals and Checks" you've mentioned are relevant for "new" release pipelines, is there something similar for "Pre-deployment conditions" in "old" release pipelines https://prnt.sc/tc4c2b ?

Comment: Unfortunately, Azure DevOps release pre-deployment approvals doesn't support configuring minimum number of approvers to complete the approval. You could submit a suggestion at website below: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21.